# TextMate2's "Go to symbol" not working for SCSS

Tags: sass, textmate2

I use TextMate 2 for Ruby on Rails projects, and "Go To Symbol" command doesn't work for .SCSS files

I have tried to update my SCSS.tmBundle when I found these links [go to symbol not supported?](https://github.com/MarioRicalde/SCSS.tmbundle/issues/17) and https://github.com/MarioRicalde/SCSS.tmbundle/pull/21

Maybe I'm not updating the Bundle correctly ? What i did is locate this file in my Mac:

```
/Users/me/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/SCSS.tmBundle
```

delete and replace it:

```
git clone https://github.com/MarioRicalde/SCSS.tmbundle.git
```

- Just one thing, the old one had 83kb, and this 666kb

¿What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The response is in knowledge about Git and forks.

I Found where is the solution, but i didn't know how to implement it: I cloned the incorrect repo from [Github](https://github.com/mads379/SCSS.tmbundle/commit/28f4ce688e0b3b52302861643740d53e5dfd5aa6)

[image]

Eventhough it does not work very well... One solution is replacing the syntax of comments:

```
/* old comments */
```

with

```
// new comments
```